# Untar file (say misc_log.tar.gz) to a directory name similar to file name (misc_log)

Tags: python

I want to untar a bunch of files in following location:

```
/users/xyz/desktop/abc.tar.gz
/users/xyz/desktop/def.tar.gz
/users/xyz/desktop/hij.tar.gz
```

to following:

```
/users/xyz/desktop/abc
/users/xyz/desktop/def
/users/xyz/desktop/hij
```

Basically I am trying to keep the directory name of the untarred contents same as the original file name. I am making modifications to following function, but it keeps untarring everything on the desktop instead of creating separate folders as I mentioned above. What am I missing here?

```
def untar(paths):
 total = 0
        for path in paths:
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                try:
                    dir_list = os.listdir(path)
                except:
                    pass
                else:
                    total += untar(os.path.join(path, new) for new in dir_list)
            elif os.path.isfile(path):
                try:
                    tarfile.open(path).extractall(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), os.path.basename((path)))))
                except:
                    pass
                else:
                    total += 1
        return total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from that piece of code:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), os.path.basename(path)))
```

and there is a problem because

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), os.path.basename(path))==path
```

you should use this instead:

```
import re
#get the archive name and replace tar.gz, or tar.bz2 or tar.wtf
#by nothing
archive_name= re.sub(r"\.tar(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})", "", os.path.basename(path))
output = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path),archive_name)
#then we extract
tarfile.open(path).extractall(output)
```

maybe you will have to create the directory `output` first, not sure...

Comment: I tried extractall as well. Didn't help. Actually when extractall didn't work, I started trying extract

Comment: they also say that "It is possible that files are created outside of path, e.g. members that have absolute filenames starting with "/" or filenames with two dots .."

Comment: is it .tar or .tar.gz ?

Comment: its tar.gz. Sorry should've mentioned earlier

Comment: So, it was the solution ?